# Problems with writing and reading files in python

Tags: python, file, text

i need to write and read multi variables in one text file

```
myfile = open ("bob.txt","w")
myfile.write(user1strength)
myfile.write("\n")
myfile.write(user1skill)
myfile.write("\n")
myfile.write(user2strength)
myfile.write("\n")
myfile.write(user2skill)
myfile.close()
```

at the moment it come's up with this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):`
`File "D:\python\project2\project2.py", line 70, in <module>`
`myfile.write(user1strength)`
`TypeError: must be str, not float`

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @JonClements that really doesn't matter

Comment: @yuvi care to explain why not?

Comment: @JonClements Because while there are version-specific solutions, with such a basic question, answers should be such that they are relevent to both python 2.X and python 3.X (That's my opinion at least).

Comment: @yuvi perhaps - but generally the more basic a question... the more it implies learning which is usually (although not always) restricted to a specific version. Also, I've seen this question in various forms a few times now, and from those attempts it was Python 3.x related... which could well invalidate some answers given if it was assumed 2.x... So, the clarification is to avoid wasting answerers time as well...

Comment: @JonClements On the one hand, I agree with you as par the answerers. on the other, I think it's a very confusing sidetrack for a beginner. Again, only my opinion

Answer (score 2):

`write` accepts strings. So you can construct a string and then pass it all at once.

```
myfile = open ("bob.txt","w")
myfile.write('\n{}\n{}\n{}'.format(user1strength, user2strength, user2skill))
myfile.close()
```

Also, if your python has support for `with`, you can do this:

```
with open("bob.txt", "w") as myfile:
    myfile.write('\n{}\n{}\n{}'.format(user1strength, user2strength, user2skill))

# code continues, file is closed properly here
```

Comment: What does with allow me to do?

Comment: `with` will automatically close the file for you, so you don't have to worry about it. Just a side suggestion unrelated to your main issue at hand.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using python3 use the print function instead.

```
with open("bob.txt", "w") as myfile:
    print(user1strength, file=myfile)
    print(user1skill, file=myfile)
    print(user2strength, file=myfile)
    print(user2skill, file=myfile)
```

The print function takes care of converting to `str` for you, and automatically adds the `\n` for you as well.  I also used a `with` block which will automatically close the file for you.

If you are on python2.6 or python2.7, you can get access to the print function with `from __future__ import print_function`.

Answer (score 0):

One your variables is probably not string type. You can only write strings to a file.

you could do something like this:

```
# this will make every variable a string
myfile = open ("bob.txt","w")
myfile.write(str(user1strength))
myfile.write("\n")
myfile.write(str(user1skill))
myfile.write("\n")
myfile.write(str(user2strength))
myfile.write("\n")
myfile.write(str(user2skill))
myfile.close()
```